# Scroll down to a new message in a chat div

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Can't make work a scrolling to bottom, when a new message appears in a chat div.

HTML:

```
<div class="content chat-body" id="messages">
    <div class="chat-message" v-for="message in messages">
        <p class="title is-6">{{ message.user.name }}</p>
        <p>{{ message.message }}</p>           
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript (pure):

```
const messages = document.getElementById('messages');

function getMessages() {
    // Prior to getting your messages.
    shouldScroll = messages.scrollTop + messages.clientHeight === messages.scrollHeight;

    // After getting your messages.
    if (!shouldScroll) {
        scrollToBottom();
    }
}

function scrollToBottom() {
    messages.scrollTop = messages.scrollHeight;
}

scrollToBottom();

setInterval(getMessages, 100);
```

However it doesn't work, throws this error in console:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollHeight' of null**

**UPDATE1**. Solved this issue by reordering script after vuejs

**UPDATE2**. How to cancel this scrolling when user is scrolling himself?

Comment: Your code works.

Comment: i suspect it has to do with the order where i put this script before vuejs include...

Comment: The div must exist before the code is executed. yes.

Comment: @AluanHaddad, that was the problem, thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with included scripts order, div must be existed before vuejs.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to call the function after #messages:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  setInterval(getMessages, 100);
});
```